# Change xterm title position

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, titlebar, xterm

I want to know if I can set the title of the terminal to the left side rather than center on Ubuntu20.04LTS? Thank you!

[this is an example of terminal title bar and I want to set the "title" to the left side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxrWo.png)

Comment: You could always add lots of spaces after the title, they get truncated when too many.  e.g. xterm -xrm "xterm*allowTitleOps: false" -T "my title  .     .      .     . "

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you for your comment, your method is feasible.

Comment: @ubfan1 But it seems three dots are added to the right side of title bar if many spaces are padded. Is there a method to avoid this?